# "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer"? when I free memory in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Input 10 string\n");
    char** inputStr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char str[16];
        int len = strlen(str);
        printf("String %d : ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", str);
        *(inputStr + i) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1));
        strcpy(*(inputStr + i), str);
    }

    /*
    do something
    */

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        free(*(inputStr + i));
    }
    free(inputStr);
    return 0;
}
```

When I proceed this code in VisualStudio 2017, error was occurred showing the message "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer".

And I erased the portion of code which using 'free' keyword, then it worked properly.

However I learned that using 'free' after 'malloc' is essential. So how can I free memory properly ???

Comment: 1) Remove `int len = strlen(str);` 2) `scanf("%s", str);` --> `scanf("%15s", str);`

Comment: Try comment out part of do-something.

Answer (score 0):

> the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer

That sounds like your program wrote memory after the end of the `inputStr` array of pointers, or perhaps past the end of one of the individual string buffers. However, the code you posted does not appear to have that problem. Perhaps you inadvertently did something past the end of one of those buffers in the `/* do something */` section?

As BLUEPIXY suggests, you do have a potential stack buffer overflow problem: if you read more than 15 chars into `str`, then you'll overwrite stack memory. And it is nonsensical to call `strlen(str)` when the content of `str` is uninitialized stack garbage.